# Installation of vs_2019 overwrite aspnet.core.1.6 library to aspnet.core 2.1,which lead to falling of vs_2017 build

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I installed vs_2019, and I am having my currently working project on vs_2017,after finishing installation of 2019 my 2017 working project are failed to build and also I am unable to open that project on 2019.
I am getting following error on 2018 build

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Standard 2.0.  Either target .NET Standard 1.6 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Standard 2.0. abc.Entities    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets   126
```

I tried with updating older version 1.6 to newly installed 2.1 aspnet core version in Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.target  which resides in build folder.

Any help is appreciated.I am unable to fix this Issue.

Comment: Share us your previous and current `*.csproj` content. And run `dotnet --info` and `dotnet --list-sdks` to share us the result. Try to reinstall the sdks which your project needs.

Comment: @TaoZhou... thanks for reply....  I am able to fix the problem with global.json  file... allows you to define which .NET Core SDK version is used when you run .NET Core CLI commands.